# Prove that $(-1)^{a/b}= \cos(180(b-a)/b)+i \sin(180(b-a)/b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I wonder why $(-1)^{a/b}= \cos(180(b-a)/b)+i \sin(180(b-a)/b)$

I got a feeling that this has something to do with complex plane.

Comment: How do youdefine he left and side?

Comment: When the base $A$ is not positive real and the exponent $e$ is not an integer, there is no consistent definition of $A^e$. In particular, $(-1)^{a/b}$ is ambiguous at best unless $b|a$, i.e. unless $a/b$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$ -1 = e^{i\pi } \implies (-1) ^{a/b}=  e^{i\pi(a/b)} $$

$$= \cos  \pi a/b +i\sin \pi a/b$$

$$= - \cos  ( \pi - \pi a/b) +i \sin (\pi -\pi a/b)$$

$$= -\cos   \pi (1 - a/b) +i \sin \pi(1-a/b)$$

$$= -\cos   \pi (b - a)/b +i \sin \pi(b-a)/b$$